# change displayed value to a name

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have an html page which gets values from cgi command and displays back to the html page I want to change the value of the first variable into a displayed word for example the first value returns a number of something like 60003. I want to display it in the html page as Name something like Operator. How can I do it ? i want also to check the variable if it equals 60003 then display operator if it equals 60004 then display operator2 etc ... 
here is the source code :

```js
$(function() {
  Display_box_menu();
});

function Display_box_menu() {
  var json_URI = "data/boxmenu_status.json";
  var pass_level = "0";

  Gen_box_menu("left-side", json_URI, pass_level);
}

function wirelessHandle(xmlDoc) {
  var infolist = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("wireless");
  if (infolist) {
    info = infolist.item(0);
    var ary = ["interPLMN", "Status_Service", "interFrequency", "interBandwidth", "interECGI", "interpci", "interrssi", "interrsrp", "interrsrq", "intersinr", "intercqi1", "intercqi2", "interrxpwr", "Status_Roam"];
    for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
      var key = ary[i];
      var vals = getDataFromTag(info, key);
      var str = "#" + key;
      if (key == "Status_Service" || key == "Status_Roam") {
        $(str).html(chkDataExist(TT(vals)));
      } else {
        if (key == "interpci" && vals == "65535") {
          $(str).html("N/A");
        } else {
          $(str).html(chkDataExist(vals));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function chkDataExist(msg) {
  if (msg == "" || msg == undefined || msg == null || msg == "NONE") {
    return "N/A";
  }
  return msg;
}

function init() {
  XHRGet(wirelessHandle, "./cgi-bin/wirelessstatus.cgi?Command=GetWireless", true, null, 1, null);
  setInterval("getWirelessData();", 2000);
}

function getWirelessData() {
  XHRGet(wirelessHandle, "./cgi-bin/wirelessstatus.cgi?Command=GetWireless", true, null, 1, null);
}

function debugLog(msg) {
  var isDebug = true;
  if (isDebug) {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="init();">
  <div id="frame">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="middle">
      <div id="left-side"></div>
      <div id="content">
        <div class="Inside_Content">
          <table class="Table">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoPLMN">PLMN</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interPLMN">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoServiceStat">Service Status</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="Status_Service">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="Frequency">Frequency(MHz)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interFrequency">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="Bandwidth">Bandwidth(kHz)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interBandwidth">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoPCI">PCI</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interpci">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="ECGI">ECGI</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interECGI">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoRSSI">RSSI(dBm)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interrssi">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoRSRP">RSRP(dBm)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interrsrp">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoRSRQ">RSRQ(dB)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interrsrq">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoSINR">SINR(dB)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="intersinr">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoCQI1">CQI1</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="intercqi1">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoCQI2">CQI2</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="intercqi2">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoTXPWR">TXPWR(dBm)</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interrxpwr">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoRoam">Roam</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="Status_Roam">N/A</span></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: where exactly do you want the certain string be displayed? You can actually use `.innerHTML `  or `.innerText`.

Comment: the first value is displayed here : 
 <td class="Td_Name" id="internetinfoPLMN">PLMN</td>
                <td class="Td_Value"><span id="interPLMN">N/A</span></td>

Comment: can you show an example for interPLMN variable